# Regex to replace text between slash and colon in xpath

Tags: regex, scala

I have xpaths e.g( "/name:ABC/dep:HR/eid:123" ). I have input string in this format and expecting output data to be in "/ABC/HR/123".

Please share your thoughts how to use regex pattern in scala or Java.

Comment: Try `(?<=/)[^:]*:`

Comment: @ ctwheels "(?<=/)[^:]*:" this pattern worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Jl5Z42/1)

```
(?<=/)[^:]*:
```

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##JcwxCwIhFADg@fwVDyeNOKk26QhrqaGlNQpe3qMMM/EkhOi3G137xzdY9Fjr83Inm2GPLgCVTKEfwMQIb9a80EOJmG/QAVcBH6TNeqN6inp7UOR6PZsv@N8lulL5ObFadkoez/o00bxNrInJheyDGEWbKHq0ZLzfBTHmU@BcSvap9Qs)

```
object Main extends App {
    val xpath = "/name:ABC/dep:HR/eid:123"
    val regex = "(?<=/)[^:]*:".r
    println(regex.replaceAllIn(xpath, ""))
}
```

Results in `/ABC/HR/123`